# No + sign in Contacts app on iPhone 5 with iOS7. Now I cannot add any contacts at all and all my old contacts were lost, too

Tags: ios, contacts, iphone

I was trying to restore my iPhone 5 because I was running out of space and the other category was taking up too much space, so I decided to restore it. However, I don't know what glitch happened during the restore, I could not restore my phone using any of the old backups so I had to restore it as a new iPhone.

I got most of my data back on my phone after doing this, except for some apps, but I had most of my other stuff still on there so I was okay with this restore. However, all of my contacts disappeared! I had made a backup of all my contacts as a `.vcf`, so I had figured out a way to get them back on my phone but my problem is that the `+` sign that should appear on the Contacts app to add new contacts is missing. Thus, I can't add any of my old or new contacts on my phone! Apple online chat support asked me to do all this step one more time, i.e. restoring it as a new iPhone, but nothing changed. I've tried going to my messages and add contacts via that, but that doesn't work either. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Your contacts may have been there all along.

First you need to go to groups and select at least one before the + button will show up.

If you have no groups or no groups selected then the contacts have nothing to add to, therefore no button.

---

**Group selected**

[image]

---

**No group selected**

[image]